Blazor tailwindCss doesn't work on all pages
I have a project in blazor, tailwindcss works correctly on many pages, but today I created a new page in the same folder as other pages, and tailwindCss does not want to work only on this page.
In browser debug i can see that all tailwindcss style loaded properly in this page, but styles don't work.
I tried to build tailwindCss by this command - npx tailwindcss -i wwwroot/tailwindcss_app.css -o wwwroot/Style/app.css --watch, restarted my PC and rebuild all project.

What do you mean "doesn't work"? Has your tailwindcss_app.css all the required classes? Is the file load properly to the browser? Are the styles applied on html elements? Can you provide a screenshot of that?
